# Creating a table in two column style page

Tags: floats, two-column, ieeetran

I want to create a table, in a two column style page (`IEEEtran`) which will range in both columns. Any idea about this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 29):

You could use the `table*` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{15}{c}}
    \hline
    One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten & Eleven & Twelve & Thirteen & Fourteen & Fifteen \\
    \hline
    Fifteen & Fourteen & Thirteen & Twelve & Eleven & Ten & Nine & Eight & Seven & Six & Five & Four & Three & Two & One \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Here is a caption.}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

There are problems with this approach, like the fact that the float will most certainly follow the page that it is defined on and could therefore cause floats to get intermixed.

Read more about page-wide floats in `twocolumn` format on the TeX FAQ entry: [Wide figures in two-column documents](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-widefigs)