# Figure spanning two columns in IEEE Trans template?

Tags: ieeetran

I am using [IEEE Transactions template](https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/author_templates.html#sect1) for a paper. The problem I am facing is that I have a figure that I want to span two columns instead of a single one. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is very similar to [IEEE-Template: Algorithm over both columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54967/5764); [Creating a table in two column style page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53384/5764). The suggestion would be to use the starred version of the float. In your case, `\begin{figure*}`...`\end{figure*}`.