# Inserting a table in a two column document

Tags: tables, sectioning, formatting, packages, two-column

So, I've been trying to insert a table so that it spans only one column into my two column document. It partially works, however it creates a large space in the other column for a reason I can't seem to figure out. A screenshot is shown below. I'm currently using the \twocolumn package. However, I'm not sure whether this or \multicols would work better with figures and tables. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  in order to understand what you're doing, we need to see a compilable example.  this looks to me like you're setting the smaller table in-line, not as a float, and there just isn't space for it in the first column.  but without code, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: welcome again. See at the link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53384/creating-a-table-in-two-column-style-page.

Comment: Use the `table*` environment, not `table`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies. You were right, I hadn't set is as a float using the table* environment. After doing so, things seem to be working out much nicer. As you can probably tell, I'm rather new to latex and still trying to learn!

Comment: table* only supports t and p.  multicols allows one to put a full width tabular in the middle of the page by using \end{multicols}.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `table` for single column floats and `table*` for double column floats.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}
\begin{document}

\section{Electronic Structure}

\input knuth

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
    \toprule
    Compound  & Phase    & Exp.\ Band Gap \\
    \midrule
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & 0.00 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sample table}
\end{table}

\input bryson

\section{Charge Transfer}

\input ward

\begin{table*}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    Compound  & Phase    & Lattice Type & Space Group & Exp.\ Band Gap \\
    \midrule
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \ch{VO_2} & Metallic & Tetragonal & P4\textsubscript{2}/mnm & 0.00 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Sample table}
\end{table*}

\input ward

\input zapf

\input darwin

\input ward

\input darwin

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! solved my problem with this being new to Elsevier template.

Answer (score 0):

@Henri Menke already answered detailed, I would just like to add a few lines for future references. The main difference to fit the table in one column  `\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}` and un-fit(!) in one column    `\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}`. And to visualize the table/figure in two column template that covers both of the columns is just to make it as  a float, for example, `\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}`, or `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}`